# The sigma algebra generated by open-dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What is the description of the sigma  algebra generated by all open-dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? Is it equal to the Borel sigma algebra?If not how is the structure of this sigma algebra?

Comment: I would say no. How can it contain any non empty(or one point) interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

1. The collection of sets which are either meager or comeager forms a $\sigma$-algebra.
2. Every open dense set is comeager, so this $\sigma$-algebra contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open dense sets.
3. This $\sigma$-algebra is missing some Borel sets.

We therefore have that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open dense sets is a proper sub-algebra of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. (On the face of it, we haven't given enough information to *characterize* what is in the $\sigma$-algebra you ask for, though.)

Comment: @Ali Measure is not mentioned anywhere on the post.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo  yes. I delet my comment.  But is the sigma algebra under question a proper subalgebra of meager-comeager algebra?

Comment: @Mike  Thank you very  much for  your answer.

Comment: I was thinking to comparision of various sigma  algebra  structure on R, up to isomorphism Twio  structure are isomorphic if there is  a bijection which preserves the structure.  I would like to know  about  comparioson between, the  algebra of :  Lesbegue measurable, Meager-comeager(which I learn from you), Borel sets,etc.... Do you have  any idea?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I'm not sure; it's not really my area of expertise. You might want to ask a new question so people who know more about sigma algebras can answer.